# How 128 bit keysize can encrypt payload using cipher 'aes-256-cbc'

Tags: openssl, cryptography, encryption-symmetric

i create key(size **128** bits) by executing below command.

```
openssl rand 128 > my.key
```

which create symmetric key of size **128** bits.

Now i want encrypt payload using cipher **aes-256-cbc**.And for that, i execute below command.

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in text.txt -k file:my.key -out text.txt.enc
```

which executed successfully and create text.txt.enc.
Now i want to decrypt the payload by using below command.

```
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -in text.txt.enc -k file:my.key -out text.txt.dec
```

which is also execute successfully.

Here my question is, **Having key size of **128** bits, how the cipher of keysize 256 can successfully encrypt/decrypt the payload ?**

Comment: Read the comment to your last question carefully! Because of the *-k* option you used, the key material is interpreted as password and *not* as key and a key derivation function is applied (by default `EVP_BytesToKey()`). This is used to derive the key (32 bytes because of AES-256) and the 16 bytes IV. If you want to pass key and IV *directly*, you must apply the *-K* and *-iv* options.

Comment: Also, instead of *-k*, *-pass* must be applied if *file:* is to be used (with *-k*, the subsequent expression is used *directly* as password).